# Inequality $\lvert\sqrt{x^2+1}\rvert\leq 2\lvert x\rvert$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{x^2+1}+t^2,~~x\in\mathbb{R}^1.
$$

In a proof that each solution of this is defined for all $t\in (-\infty,+\infty)$, it is said that
$$
\left\lvert\frac{dx}{dt}\right\rvert\leq 2\lvert x\rvert +t^2.
$$

Sorry, I do not see this. To my opinion this is only true if $x>1/3$.

Comment: $\lvert\sqrt{x^2+1}\rvert\leq 2\lvert x\rvert$ is definitely wrong for small $x$, e.g. for $x = 0$.

Comment: Then there must be some mistake in the proof.

Comment: It is true if and only if $|x|\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.