# How to see this inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Consider
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{x^2+1}+t^2,\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Then I do not see why it is
$$
\lvert\frac{dx}{dt}\rvert\leq 2\lvert x\rvert+t^2.
$$

Comment: Why do you think that the estimate holds? It is wrong for small $x$. (There was a quite similar question some days ago.)

Comment: The solution says: The right-hand side grows not faster than linearly with $x$: $\lvert\frac{dx}{dt}\rvert\leq 2\lvert x\rvert +t^2$. Do not understand this.

Comment: Same question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560181/inequality-lvert-sqrtx21-rvert-leq-2-lvert-x-rvert-for-all-x. Where does the problem come from? Is an initial value given?

Comment: Maybe I just get the author wrong, since he does not say that this estmiation holds but that it means that the right hand-side does not grow fast than linearly in x, but I do not understand this.

Comment: $1 + |x| + t^2$ would be an upper bound for the rhs, does that help?

Comment: No, since for the rest of the solution it is necessary to have an estimation of the form $a(t)x+b(t)$.

Comment: Well, $\sqrt{x^2+1} \le 2 |x|$ does not hold generally. I would suggest that you provide more information about that "solution". Otherwise we can only guess about the author's intention.

Comment: You are right. I contacted the author.

Comment: @Rhjg You could incorporate the constant term $1$ that Martin suggested in your $b(t)=1+t^2$.

Comment: 'the rhs grows no faster than' is usually a term chosen when one looks at large $x$. For large $x$ the inequality is easily seen to be true.

Answer (score 0):

The steps that come to mind are

$$\begin{array}{}
\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{x^2+1}+t^2 \\
|\frac{dx}{dt}|=|\sqrt{x^2+1}+t^2| \\
|\frac{dx}{dt}|\le|\sqrt{x^2+1}|+|t^2| & \qquad \text{Triangle Inequality} \\
|\frac{dx}{dt}|\le \sqrt{x^2+1} + t^2  \\
\end{array}$$

**If** we had $\sqrt{x^2+1} \le 2|x|$, then we could get your final result but

$$\begin{array}{}
\sqrt{x^2+1} \le 2|x| \\
x^2+1 \le 4x^2 \\
3x^2 \ge 1 \\
x^2 \ge \frac{1}{3} \\
|x| \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt3}
\end{array}$$

So we can say that

$$|\frac{dx}{dt}|\le \ 2|x| + t^2, \qquad \quad |x| \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$